# JAVA program that checks if a triangle is scalene, isosceles, equilateral, or not a triangle

Tags: java, logic

I am trying to write java program to see if a triangle is scalene, isosceles, equilateral or not a triangle. With the integers I used it is supposed to be not a triangle (1, 1, 30). But I keep getting scalene and not a triangle together. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

```
public class Tri {

    static void checkTriangle(int x, int y, int z) 
    { 

        // Check for equilateral triangle 
        if (x == y && y == z ) 
            System.out.println("Equilateral Triangle"); 

        // Check for isoceles triangle 
        else if (x == y || y == z || z == x ) 
            System.out.println("Isoceles Triangle"); 

        // Check for scalene triangle
        else if (x != y || y!= z || z != x)
            System.out.println("Scalene Triangle");
        {
            // Check for not a triangle 
            if (x + y < z || x + z < y || y + z > x) 
                System.out.println("Not a triangle");

        }
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        { 

            int x = 1, y = 1, z = 30; 

            checkTriangle(x, y, z); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I come from a background where triangles are at plotted on a 2 dimensional plane (or more) with 3 points can you explain why the method only takes (x,y,z) instead of a series of points?

Comment: x y z comes from the three sides

Comment: Apologize I had to reword my comment, check edit. I'm just thinking should this checkTriangle method take a series of points rather than just (x,y,z). But perhaps the real issue is the code is malformed I'm seeing some odd curly braces and parts that should be code but are not formatted as such.

Comment: Now I realize you either meant that x, y, z represent the lengths of the three sides OR the angle. In the question that was not described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for not a triangle condition first. As below:

```
static void checkTriangle(int x, int y, int z) 
{ 

    // Check for not a triangle 
    if (x + y < z || x + z < y || y + z > x) {
        System.out.println("Not a triangle");
    } else {

    // Check for equilateral triangle 
    if (x == y && y == z ) 
        System.out.println("Equilateral Triangle"); 

    // Check for isoceles triangle 
    else if (x == y || y == z || z == x ) 
        System.out.println("Isoceles Triangle"); 

    // Check for scalene triangle
    else if (x != y || y!= z || z != x)
        System.out.println("Scalene Triangle");
    }
} 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    { 

        int x = 1, y = 1, z = 30; 

        checkTriangle(x, y, z); 
    } 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the existing answer:

You should check whether a triangle can be formed or not first, then only you should check whether its scalene, isoceles or equilateral.

The order you should check in is :

1. check if a triangle can be formed.
2. check if its equilateral.
3. check if its isoceles.
4. you dont even have to check now as it has to be scalene.

Why this order?

Every triangle is a scalene triangle.
Every equilateral is also an isoceles and scalene triangle.

Scalene triangle is superset of isoceles triangle and equilateral triangle.
Isoceles triangle is superset of Equilateral traingle.

so your function would look like this:

```
static void checkTriangle(int x, int y, int z) 
{ 

    //Checking for whether its a triangle first

    // Check for not a triangle 
    if (x + y < z || x + z < y || y + z > x) {
        System.out.println("Not a triangle");
    } else {

    // Check for equilateral triangle 
    if (x == y && y == z ) 
        System.out.println("Equilateral Triangle"); 

    // Check for isoceles triangle 
    else if (x == y || y == z || z == x ) 
        System.out.println("Isoceles Triangle"); 

    // Check for scalene triangle
    else if (x != y || y!= z || z != x)
        System.out.println("Scalene Triangle");
    }
}
```